# Export and send excel file in mail from C# code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, export

I have a link from where file can be exported using rdlc(in excel format). But now when clicks on send mail, a pop up opens in that the file should be exported and added as attachment in hyperlink, and when click on send mail, it should also go with the mail as an attachement. How can I do so in C#?

Comment: I am doing R&D but not getting any idea what to do? I want to save file temporary on the server and when mail is sent, it should be deleted from server

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.
Just exchange the property values with yours.

```
public void SendMail(string package, string mailTo, string subject, string body) {
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.From = new MailAddress(mailAddr, alias);
    mail.Sender = new MailAddress(mailAddr, alias);
    mail.ReplyTo = new MailAddress(mailAddr, alias);
    string[] to = mailTo.Split(new char[] { ',', ';', '|', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    for (int i = 0; i < to.Length; i++) mail.To.Add(to[i]);
    mail.Subject = subject;
    mail.Body = body;

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(server, 25);
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "", "");
    smtp.EnableSsl = false;
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtp.Send(mail);    
}
```